# MacBook Pro Key getting stuck or won't register

Tags: keyboard, macbook

The 'e' key on my Macbook Pro (Late 2013) is not working properly. It works maybe 50% of the time. When I try to press 'e' over and over again, it eventually acts like it's stuck down. I've taken off the black key itself along with the plastic mechanism that attaches to it, but it's still having issues occasionally. It was really dirty, and I got a lot of small hair out of this area but I didn't use any cleaning fluid on it because I'm not sure if I can.

How is it still *occasionally* sticking despite me directly pressing on the rubber button? Can I clean the exposed area? And what should I clean it with - rubbing alcohol?

Comment: theres no point in keeping that mac anyhow

Comment: Really? Okay. *throws out window*

Answer (score 0):

I would say a cotton wool bud or similar soft-ended tool is ideal for soaking up any small liquid deposits and lifting out detritus. Make sure you don't stress the delicate plastic of the scissor-lift mechanism too much though... If you have anything such as an anti-static cleaner that could be worth using just to clean the key area out completely. (I can't imagine that it will need to be anti-static but if you use an Alcohol based cleaner use it sparingly).

I cleaned out an iMac keyboard recently using a cotton wool bud with some foam clean and that seemed to do the trick!